# Disable laptop headphone port to default to built-in speaker

Tags: 16.04, sound

I got my headphone's plug stuck in my laptop port and tried to get it out via some solutions I saw in the internet(using super-glue etc..). None of them worked.

Now, I can't hear anything out of my laptop because it thinks that the headphones are connected. I'm trying to disable the port and activate the speakers sound instead. Any idea how to do it? I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain the laptop has onboard speakers?

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal window and type `alsamixer`

- you can chose the sound card pressing `F6` if not already chosen by default
- you can mute/unmute pressing `m`
- you should have sliders for speakers headphones
- see help `h` or `F1` for more details

Comment: I disabled auto-mute and put on 100 every single bar. I still hear no sound from my laptop

Comment: have you found both speakers and headphone bars? is the speakers bar unmuted(no `mm` underneath the bar)?; maybe your speakers are physically connected to audio jack in which case you need a service intervention to take out the broken jack part.. maybe some thin tweezers